# CMMotionActivityManager returning automotive even when device is stationary

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, cllocationmanager

We are developing a iOS 9.X iPhone and iPad app which tracks user activities. Based on the activities the app will show different screens with some different activity tracking details. The app is not supposed to show anything when the device is stationary.
We are able to track when the user is in a car and the trip is tracked well.

However we are seeing that even though the user device is stationary and/or the app is in background, motion co-processor is returning the activity as Automotive with medium confidence level. This is creating multiple false tracking being logged. Such activities have very small distance travelled and/or minimum to no difference in Lat/Long values.

How do we ignore/stop these trips from happening?

Comment: You study what data you are receiving, and write code that ignores data that you think is not motion or not car-based motion, improving your code until you get satisfying results.

Comment: @gnasher729, we are doing exactly that. But the issue is we are not able to look forward to proactively cancel a trip to cancel even before it is logged. Our logic was the trip should be either of type automotive and substantial distance has been covered and location change is substantial. Strangely, We are getting a true for all these factors.